# What is the effect of a soft expire in Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

Below is the documentation for the cache invalidation in volley.  I am not clear on what the effect of a soft expire would be?  Also how does Volley update the cache? Is it based on http headers only?  Or can there be a fixed time for a cache item?

```
   /**
   * Invalidates an entry in the cache.
   * @param key Cache key
   * @param fullExpire True to fully expire the entry, false to soft expire
   */
   public void invalidate(String key, boolean fullExpire);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A soft expiry will return cached data, but in the background will retrieve new content so that your next request will be cached with newer data.

Comment: I am trying to do this using pagination with recyclerview , as i reach the end of the view i want the newly loaded list to be added to the cache , i am already getting the new list and adding it at the end of my oldList , what is the optimat way to empty cache on LoadMore() and add new fetched items to the cache?